# Jekyll plugin not working

Tags: plugins, github, jekyll

I have developed a simple Jekyll plugin, to generate the categories pages. IT works fine on my local system but does not work on github site.

Here is the source of the plugin:

https://github.com/madhur/madhur.github.com/blob/master/_plugins/site_process.rb

It should generate a page such as this:

http://www.madhur.co.in/categories/Security.html

However its not generated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GitHub doesn't allow Jekyll plugins, turns out we don't want you running arbitrary code on our servers :)

Answer (score 3):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369397/jekyll-plugin-not-work-on-github/20377640#20377640) from Andión is better.

You can just upload the contents of the `_site` folder. That way you will simply push the static site. A simple way of doing that would be moving your `.git/` folder to the `_site` folder, committing and pushing those changes. After that you will generate your site as usual and then push the changes to github from the `_site` folder. –  Andión