# jekyll plugin not work on github

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll

I want to change the order of pages in navitation bar by using `jekyll-plugins / weighted_pages.rb` from [here](https://github.com/aucor/jekyll-plugins).

This plugin work very well on my localhost but github.
I find the navitation bar is empty on github host, which seems this plugin does not work. 
How can I solve this problem?

I copy `weighted_pages.rb` code below:

```
# Generates a copy of site.pages as site.weighted_pages
# with pages sorted by weight attribute. Pages with no
# weight specified are placed after the pages with specified weight.

module Jekyll

  class WeightedPagesGenerator < Generator
    safe true

    def generate(site)
      site.config['weighted_pages'] = site.pages.sort_by { |a| 
        a.data['weight'] ? a.data['weight'] : site.pages.length }
    end

  end

end
```

Add `weight` attribute to the front matter of your `pages (like weight: 1)` and use `site.weighted_pages` instead of `site.pages` in your loops.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Github pages does not support plugins. From [jekyll's documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins):

> GitHub Pages is powered by Jekyll, however all Pages sites are generated using the --safe option to disable custom plugins for security reasons. Unfortunately, this means your plugins won’t work if you’re deploying to GitHub Pages.

The same documentation page also gives you a workaround:

> You can still use GitHub Pages to publish your site, but you’ll need to convert the site locally and push the generated static files to your GitHub repository instead of the Jekyll source files.

Comment: But the `_site` floder can not be uploaded,what should I do?

Comment: You can just upload the *contents* of the `_site` folder. That way you will simply push the static site.

A simple way of doing that would be moving your `.git/` folder to the `_site` folder, committing and pushing those changes. After that you will generate your site as usual and then push the changes to github from the `_site` folder.

Comment: Yes,it is.I am sorry I forgot to check the answer promptly.Thank you very much.