# why jekyll tag not working on github give 404 erro but it works on localhost

Tags: github, tags, localhost, jekyll

I use [this](http://charliepark.org/tags-in-jekyll/) tutorial for create tags on jekyll its work correctly on localhost when I click on a tag link it take me to the /tags/tag_name page but when  I push it to the github this directory (/tags/tag_name page) give me 404 error! how can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that github **disables custom plugins** for security reasons, thus, the .rb file that this tutorial uses will not work. There does seem to be a workaround, however, which involves compiling your Jekyll source code to the `_site` directory before pushing to github server. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20369397/jekyll-plugin-not-work-on-github?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

If you site lives at http://example.com/mysite, you need to set `baseurl: /mysite` in `_config.yml`, and call you pages like this :

```
<a href="{{ site.baseurl }}/tags/tag_namepage">Tag</a>
```