# Facebook-based comments not working in jekyll blog on github

Tags: github, jekyll, facebook-comments

I set up a jekyll blog on github. I tried to add comments to posts through  Facebook, following this link:

https://blog.webjeda.com/jekyll-comments/

But the comments aren't loaded on site but perfectly loaded on localhost.

My site is http://kitchen.jus.in/, hosted at https://github.com/jus/kitchen.

I don't add any `url`, `baseurl` in `config.yml`.

Thanks for the advice...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jekyll plugin not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646744/jekyll-plugin-not-working)

Comment: It's not a plugin

Comment: I forgot to mention that the above code is perfectly working on localhost

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by adding `url` in my `config.yml`.

Thanks.

Comment: This helped a lot!